# How to make this part of the site clickable (redirect to home page)?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been working on my first Wordpress web as a part of a project at my university and my client bought and gave me this theme that is quite limited in some areas.

He wants me to make this text on mobile devices be clickable and to redirect users to home page after clicking it. I don't know how to do it though. I have only basic HTML, CSS and PHP knowledge.

Here is the screenshot of how does the UI of Theme Options looks like in WP - this is the only thing that I am allowed to change when it comes to the top bar of navigation:
[image: Interface of Appearance → Theme Options → Logo Text]

Here is the screenshot of how does it actually looks like on web:
[image: Currently it looks like this]

I was trying to put a simple a href tag just like everywhere else in this bar inside the user interface of the theme options but it resulted in some error - so this is not the way.

Also I can view and edit anything that is inside folders through WinSCP, so I was trying to find the .php file that Chrome Dev Tools were showing me, but I could not find that "index:112" that is showing up. I don't know - what does that 112 stands for? And is this the way how can I add a href to that? I was thinking that I would just wrap it inside a div and add an a href to that div and that would make it.

If anyone has some easy solution, that would be nice and I would be grateful. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the logo is likely in a `header.php` file in the theme directory. You’ll need to do some PHP, HTML, and CSS work, but should be able to achieve the desired result relatively easily.